# Не срабатывает margin-top

Tags: html, css

Ответы искал, как мне сделать отступ без всяких border и т.п. Можно ли так вообще?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <p>Airliner</p>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #04002B;
}

p {
    color: white;

    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Точнее, он работает, но перетягивает вместе  собой родительский блок

Comment: что значит "перетягивает"?

Comment: Создаётся впечатление, что он к себе приклеивает родителя и вместе с ним уже делает отступ от окна браузера

Comment: [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

действительно странное поведение

как я его обошел:

**вариант 1:**

прозрачная граница и стиль чтоб граница не влияла на размеры блоков:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #04002B;
    
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

**вариант 2:**

добавляем в `header` еще один блок, в котором не видим текст

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #04002B;
}

header > span {
    font-size: 0px;
}

p {
    color: white;

    margin-top: 50px;
}

</style>

    <header><span>X</span>
        <p>Airliner</p>
    </header>
```

**вариант 3:**

добавляем в `p` стиль `position: absolute;`

```
p {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;

    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

недостаток - этот блок выпадает из очереди и не влияет уже на остальные блоки в `header`

**ВАРИАНТ 4 (ОКОНЧАТЕЛЬНЫЙ):**

блок `p` имеет свойство `display: inline` (как `span` и прочий мусор), чтобы все было хорошо ему нужно свойство `display: inline-block`:

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
    
    color: white;

    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: **Благодарю! **

Comment: @Lirika, нашел истинное решение проблемы!!! смотрите вариант 4

Comment: Чёрт, так и знал, что-то с дисплеями связано, я так со <span> уже мучился. Спасибо ещё раз!

Comment: @Zhihar а с каких пор "блок `p` имеет свойство `display: inline`"?

Comment: @fanfer, ну может не так выразился - поведение у него как у `display: inline`, хотя вот тут http://htmlbook.ru/css/display конкретно написано, что `p` - это `inline`

Comment: @Zhihar там написано, что inline как раз отменяет блочное поведение у `p` "inline - Элемент отображается как встроенный. Использование блочных тегов, таких как <div> и <p>, автоматически создает перенос и показывает содержимое этих тегов с новой строки. Значение inline отменяет эту особенность, поэтому содержимое блочных элементов начинается с того места, где окончился предыдущий элемент."

Comment: @fanfer, да, точно, скосячил, ну значит просто `inline-block` - это решение описанной автором проблемы и все :)